# Homogenized Mehta integral

Tags: pr.probability, rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

For $a=(a_1,a_2)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ let me use the notation from classical invariant theory
$$
(ab)=a_1b_2-a_2b_1\ .
$$
If I run out of letters $a,b,c,\ldots$, then I will switch to $a^{(1)},a^{(2)},a^{(3)},\ldots$

Consider the following homogenized analogue of the complex Mehta integral
$$
\int_{(\mathbb{C}^2)^n}
e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^2|a^{(i)}_{\ell}|^2}
\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}|(a^{(i)}a^{(j)})|^{2\gamma}\ 
\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{\ell=1}^{2}\frac{d\Re a^{(i)}_{\ell}d\Im a^{(i)}_{\ell}}{\pi}\ .
$$

Is there a simple explicit formula for it?

This was inspired from this other MO question

[Integration of a function over 7-sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393706/integration-of-a-function-over-7-sphere)