# Complex beta function $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (x^2+y^2)^{\alpha-1}((1-x)^2+y^2)^{\beta-1} \,dx\,dy$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration

I am interested in showing that the integral
\begin{align}
& \int_{\mathbb{C}} |z|^{2\alpha-2}|1-z|^{2\beta - 2} \,dA(z) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (x^2+y^2)^{\alpha-1}((1-x)^2+y^2)^{\beta-1} \,dx\,dy \\[8pt] = {} & \frac{\sin(\pi \alpha)\sin(\pi \beta)}{\sin(\pi(\alpha+\beta))}B(\alpha,\beta)^2
\end{align}
for $\Re{(\alpha)}, \Re{(\beta)} >0, \Re(\alpha+\beta)<1$, where $B$ is the usual beta function.

It is a special case of the [complex Selberg integral](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/38/4/385/1530985) calculated by K. Aomoto. In his paper, he makes use of homology theory but states that this special case was calculated by R. S. Strichartz using a strictly analytical argument. The reference for this was a preprint 'Complex hypergeometric integrals' 1985 which I am unable to find. I am looking for either a  proof using minimal homology theory or a reference.

Comment: Your integral can be written as $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{r^{2\alpha-1}}{\left(1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2\right)^{1-\beta}}\,dr\,d\theta.$$

Comment: probably related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394010/homogenized-mehta-integral?noredirect=1&lq=1